# super dealloc EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, memory-management

While analysing our project Xcode came with a posibe leak notification at a custom UIBarButtonItem.
I fixed the leak, but while loading the view for the second time, [super dealloc] gives a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Removing the autorelease from the UIBarButtonItem (so returning the warning):

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolbar] autorelease];
```

gives no problems while reloading the screen.

Custom UIBarButtonItem and dealloc code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // create a toolbar to have the buttons at the right side of the navigationBar
    UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 44.01)];
    toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [toolbar setTranslucent:YES];

    // create the array to hold the buttons, which then gets added to the toolbar
    NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];


    // Create a comments button
    propertiesButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(properties)];
    [buttons addObject:propertiesButton];
    [propertiesButton release];

    // Create a comments button
    commentaryButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose target:self action:@selector(comments)];
    [buttons addObject:commentaryButton];
    [commentaryButton release];

    // create a versions button
    versionsButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(versions)];
    [buttons addObject:versionsButton];
    [versionsButton release];

    // create a save button
    downloadButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize target:nil action:@selector(download)];
    [buttons addObject:downloadButton];
    [downloadButton release];

    // stick the buttons in the toolbar
    [toolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];

    [buttons release];

    // and put the toolbar in the nav bar
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolbar] autorelease];
    [toolbar release];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [popOverController release];
    [propertiesButton release];
    [downloadButton release];
    [versionsButton release];
    [commentaryButton release];
    [webView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

With NSZombieEnabled i get

```
'2011-08-01 10:30:36.571 ProjectName[100:707] *** -[UIBarButtonItem release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1fb330'
```

We are not sure how to fix the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are releasing propertiesButton, downloadButton, versionsButton, commentaryButton two times. First time in `viewDidLoad` and again in `dealloc`.

You don't have to release them in `dealloc` as you have already released it in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Very thanks! It is a routine that when I am creating a property that I add them to the dealloc method. But when I am passing it trough an other object I release them too. Still weird that xcode tell me the problem is at the [super dealloc]. Thanks again1

Answer (score 0):

You already release your UIBarButtonItem's after you add them to array - so you **must not** release them again in dealloc method - those extra release calls result in sending message to already deallocated buttons and make your app crash

Answer (score 0):

As i see it, you are releasing your buttons twice. First time in your viewDidLoad() function and finally in your dealloc function.